# Lazy load images not indexing in google

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading

I have a problem, I am loading images width lazy load with data-src but they are not indexed by google, I am looking for posible solutions and I can read to use intersetion observer (that it is not compatible with explorer, other problem for me), but I think they use the same technique inserting the real image in data-src and when is in viewport inject the image in the src attribute. Anybody has experience with that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about the [official documentation on "lazy-loaded content"](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/lazy-loading)?

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas mentioned in a comment, an answer is within [Google's documentation entitled "Fix lazy-loaded content"](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/lazy-loading):

> ## Load content when it's visible in the viewport
>
> To ensure that Googlebot sees all content on your page, make sure that your lazy
>   loading implementation loads all relevant content whenever it is
>   visible in the viewport. Here are a few examples on how you can do
>   this:
>
> - [IntersectionObserver API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/intersectionobserver) and a [polyfill](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill)
> - A JavaScript library that
>     supports loading data when it enters the viewport.
>
> Make sure to [test
>   your implementation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/lazy-loading#test).

## Note

You can use IntersectionObserver API in Internet Explorer (and Edge...) if you use https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill (according to its [browser support list](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill#browser-support)).

In this case ["polyfill"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) essentially means an implementation that brings the browser up to compliance or compatibility with the otherwise unsupported API.

Comment: Not sure how to explain it but google is not helping in any way (`make sure that your lazy loading implementation loads all relevant content whenever it is visible`), well yes, that is what I am doing, and Google is not indexing it. Is not like I am never showing the images and expect them to be indexed.